# Why are there error codes in my SQLite db files

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app which include adding data to database.After i run the app and input some data i want to check if the data has been successfully added to my db.
But the my.db3 file shows:
SQLite format 3 and some error codes

Here is my code(TheInputButton):

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String sMiles=miles.getText().toString();
        String sDate=date.getText().toString();
        String sPrice=price.getText().toString();
        String sCosts=costs.getText().toString();
        try{
            db.execSQL("insert into fuelcost values('" + sMiles + "','" +sDate + "','"+sPrice+"','"+sCosts+"')");
           }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            db.execSQL("create table fuelcost(miles vachar(10) primary key,date varchar(10),price varchar(10),costs varchar(10))");
        }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the errors?

Comment: I can't post a image.
There are some meaningless symbols in the my.db3 file